# How to test WebService calls in Play 2.1?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, scala-2.10

I'm scraping a website that expects GET parameters and a cookie. I want to know whether the correct parameters and cookies are being sent. Being able to test HTTP headers, POST data etc. would be very useful too later on.

The best way to do this seems to me to start a webserver, have the scraping code call a URL that points to the webserver and see if everything is arriving correctly on the server. Having an easy way to setup a mock external webserver would also be great for integration testing.

It's simple code like this:

```
  def getResource(a: String, b: String, c: String) =
    WS.url("http://www.example.com")
          .withQueryString("x" -> a, "y" -> b)
          .withHeaders("Cookie" -> c)
          .get()
```

I'm using ScalaTest to do my unit tests.

Does Play provide anything to test these sort of things easily? Are there other easy to use libraries that would suit my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try embedded [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html) inside a unit test, you can fake the external service the way you want

Comment: I really like how simple the Jetty library is, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default way to test a Play 2 application is by using [specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/). In Your case one can use a [functional tests](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFunctionalTest) for testing webserver like:

```
"run in a server" in new WithServer {
  await(getResource(a,b,c)).status must equalTo(OK)
}
```

See [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaTest) for testing Play 2 apps.

Comment: This technique is for testing the application itself, it doesn't allow you to test whether you're calling external services correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `WithServer` starts the internal server. And one can be omitted. But this technique does allow you to test any function, including the external services calls. Why not?

Comment: I want to test whether the HTTP request actually arrives as it should with correct headers/GET parameters/POST data on the external service. And I want to do it without actually calling the external service, since it might not respond very fast, it could be down, calling the service might trigger things I don't want to trigger during a test (API access limits, POST requests that mutate data on the external service) and so on.

I basically want to mock an external HTTP server, check whether it gets requests and do some checks on the request data.